# How to define helper for a template inside a template in meteor?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

I followed the **todo app** tutorial from [this site](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates) and I have following question,

How do I write functions for *task* template which is inside the *imports/ui/body.html*

For instance, if this is my `body.html`

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}} 
     <button onclick="{{buyItem this._id}}" >Buy</button>
  </li>
</template>
```

looks like it's not inheriting the helper functions from parent template i.e. if I define in

> Template.body.helpers()

in `body.js`

Comment: In the `.js` file in the same directory did you put `import "./body.html";`? If not, put that at the top (first line) of the `.js` file.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly like how its given in the tutorial...